# git reset --soft HEAD^ for initial commit

Tags: git

Could someone please tell me what would be an equivalent of `git reset --soft HEAD^` for an initial commit? I'm trying to find a really safe one-liner without any deletions :)

To further clarify: I want all the files I tediously added to be in the index and ready for committing after the command is run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you found, for the initial commit using `git reset --soft HEAD^` doesn't work.

What does work is using `git update-ref -d HEAD`.

But provided that there is only one branch and one commit, it's can be easier to just delete the `.git` directory and start over. Of course, you should only do that if you know what you are doing.

Comment: That would also completely erase the git history, and it's not clear whether that's what nzn was asking for in the question.

Comment: @DavidZ: If it's the initial commit (emphasis on initial) and there is only one branch then there is no history and therefore nothing to lose.

Comment: Sure, that's true; I'm just saying, it's not clear from the question whether that's the situation being asked about, and if someone who is not in that situation deletes the `.git` directory, they could do a lot of damage.

Comment: @DavidZ: The question looks a bit ambiguous but I think I read it correctly. You are correct though that deleting the `.git` can cause a lot of damage if you don't know what you are doing so I have revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Of course hopefully the OP will come back and clarify the question.

Comment: As I have mentioned I don't want to delete anything and to further clarify: I want all the files I tediously added to be in the index to be added after the command is run.

Comment: @nzn: The git command I gave does what you want. Test a copy of your repo to verify.

Comment: No, "there is nothing to lose" is _definitely_ false. Anything you git added is still in the repo, in the state it was in when you added it.  If you've changed it in your worktree since, deleting the `.git` directory will lose what you added, and it will also lose the record of _which_ things don't have the same content you added before.

Comment: @jthill: It's rare but I have run into this exact situation myself where I had just run `git init`, made the first commit but then wanted to rollback my actions. In this scenario, I always chose to delete the `.git` directory and start over because ultimately there is nothing to lose. You know what I'm talking about and I am not interested in arguing over semantics so let's just say we value the `.git` directory differently when there is only one branch and one commit and leave it at that.

Comment: Not a good answer - the command `git update-ref -d HEAD` deletes the .git folder. Not always what you want.

Comment: @NickManning: `get-update-ref` is for updating the object name stored in a ref safely. Passing `-d` results in the deletion of the named ref. This is noted in the git reference manual and can be verified by creating a test repository with an initial commit.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to run `git rebase -i --root` and edit the first commit. But the files from the first commit do not return to the working tree, so I tried the command in this answer, and suddenly my directory isn't recognized as being a git repo, although the .git folder is still there on closer inspection.

Comment: @NickManning: This command is the equivalent of `git reset --soft HEAD^` but for an initial commit. It undos the first commit and adds the cumulative contents back to the index (i.e. it's for when you made the first commit and want to undo that commit and not for undoing changes in/to files).

Comment: @NickManning: A built-in git command causing the `.git` directory to become unrecognizable isn't something I'm familiar with. You should be able to manually copy the repository, perform `git init`, find the deleted commits with `git fsck --lost-found` and restore them by hand. But that is a bit beyond the scope of this question.